# Couldn't find general-purpose registers in core file

Tags: gdb, arm, shared-libraries

i get the below error when i try to debug the core file. How to solve this issue. 
Just some days ago it was working fine.
I tried running "/sbin/ldconfig" with root provileges. Code is compiled with :

```
g++ -fPIC -ggdb
```

My executable is 32-bit binary:

```
$ file appl

ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked 
(uses shared libs), not stripped.


user@ubu:/mnt/hgfs/share$ gdb appl  core.11_416


GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /mnt/hgfs/share/appl...done.

warning: Couldn't find general-purpose registers in core file.

warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 9 libraries, e.g. /lib/libdl.so.2.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
Core was generated by `appl'.


warning: Couldn't find general-purpose registers in core file.
#0  <unavailable> in ?? ()
(gdb) i shared
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
                    No          /lib/libdl.so.2
                    No          /opt/lib/libappl.so
                    No          /lib/librt.so.1
                    No          /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
                    No          /lib/libm.so.6
                    No          /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
                    No          /lib/libc.so.6
                    No          /lib/libpthread.so.0
                    No          /lib/ld-linux.so.3
(gdb) 
(gdb) show solib-search-path
The search path for loading non-absolute shared library symbol files is .
(gdb) show sysroot
The current system root is "".
(gdb) 
(gdb) show archi
The target architecture is set automatically (currently i386)
```

I am using VMware running ubuntu 12.04

```
user@ubu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubu 3.2.0-36-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 8 21:41:24 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
user@ubu:~$
```

### **EDIT : 20-Mar-2013**

@SCOTT: Thanks for reply. I will try this out. The same setup was working fine earlier and i was able to debug with GDB. Once i did a "apt-get update", and since then GDB is complaining the above errors. One difference which i can make out was earlier when GDB was working the verion was showing:

```
This GDB was configured as "i486-linux-gnu".
```

Now the the version after update shows:

```
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu"
```

That's all the difference which i can see or understand.

The ARM tool chain which i use doesn't have the GDB provided with. The g++ is compiled for Intel. I use this same g++ to build the executable now also.

```
$ file g++
g++: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped
```

The provided cross-compiler executable which i use are as below. But when i got this error I was using the normal gdb (installed on Ubuntu) command only which is at "/usr/bin/gdb":

```
user@ubu:/opt/cs/bin$ ls
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gdb

... etc ...
```

Am i using wrong GDB here. If it was wrong GDB, why it was working earlier now why not? Should i use this arm-none-linux-gnueabi-GDB to debug the ARM cross compiled application, which is compiled with:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++  appl.cpp  -o appl


user@ubu:~$ which gdb
/usr/bin/gdb
```

Comment: ` This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".` Is this a x86 host trying to debug arm core dump?

Comment: I am using Windows-XP with VM-ware running Ubuntu 12.04, on which i cross-compiled source for ARM. And running GDB on same VM-ware running ubuntu 12.04

Comment: You need a GDB supporting arm / cross compilation. Current one seems targeting x86, which would explain missing registers and since it is probably also compiled for another system that would explain missing library search, path etc.

Comment: But on the same setup i was able to debug earlier. I did a "apt-get update " and since then something has gone wrong, which i am not able to find :(

Comment: `apt-get update` ~ you either overwrite your previous installation / setup or you have another gdb somewhere in your path.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong gdb. Grab the [Linaro ARM toolchain](https://launchpad.net/linaro-toolchain-binaries/trunk/2013.02/+download/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.02-01-20130221_linux.tar.xz) tarball, extract it and run:

```
$ gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.02-01-20130221_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb appl  core.11_416
<...>
This GDB was configured as "--host=i686-build_pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf".
<...>
```

Note the gdb you're using shows "This GDB was configured as "**i686-linux-gnu**"". You want one that shows **"--host=i686-build_pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf"** (or similar ARM Linux triplet in target).

Usually people wouldn't mix up a gcc targetting **arm-linux-gnueabihf** with a gdb targetting **i686-linux-gnu** because the compiler, linker and debugger commands would all start with the same prefix, i.e. **arm-linux-gnueabihf-{gcc,gdb,ld,gas}** etc. How did you end up with your particular gcc and gdb combination?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will try this out. The same setup was working fine earlier and i was able to debug with GDB. Once i did a "apt-get update", and since then GDB is complaining the above errors.

Comment: I have updated the question with some more details on how i got in to this situation. I still have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had compiled GDB in my cross-compiler toolchain. It was present in one of the bin directories of build directory. You may check for a similar gdb